# View a function source code in firefox inspector

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

In chrome, when you type a function in the console, the source code for that function is outputted. For example

```
>    $.rails.confirm
     function (message) {
        return confirm(message);
      }
```

But in firefox inspector's console, it just outputs

```
[object Function]
```

How do I see a function's source code in Firefox inspector, like in chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write in console function.toString(). Example:

alert.toString() will output:

```
"function alert() {
    [native code]
}"
```